# python import a list from another file to pick random

Tags: python, list, dictionary

When I copy and paste the list to the file, it successfully picks random but not from the words.py file. I must have something to do with concatenation type mismatch because it gives me an error

```
print('random word is ' + random.choice(example))
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "dict") to str
```

This is the code I am using.

```
import random
from words import words 
import string

print('random word is ' + random.choice(words))
```

This is the beginning portion of the dictionary. It has over 5000 words.

`words = [{"data":["aback","abaft","abandoned","abashed","aberrant","abhorrent","abiding","abject","ablaze","able","abnormal","aboard","aboriginal","abortive","abounding","abrasive","abrupt","absent","absorbed","absorbing","abstracted","absurd","abundant","abusive","accept","acceptable","accessible","accidental","account","accurate","achiever","acid","acidic","acoustic","acoustics","acrid","act"]}]`

Comment: It's because the the result returned from `random.choice(words)` is a dictionary. Could you share what's the data structure looks like for the imported `words`?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What exactly is ```words.py```?

Comment: Thanks! Sorry if my question structure is bad, I still learning. So words.py is the file i have the dictionary is in. The dictionary is also named words, I don't know if thats where the issue is.

Comment: This is the beginning portion of the dictionary. It has over 5000 words.      
```words = [{"data":["aback","abaft","abandoned","abashed","aberrant","abhorrent","abiding","abject","ablaze","able","abnormal","aboard","aboriginal","abortive","abounding","abrasive","abrupt","absent","absorbed","absorbing","abstracted","absurd","abundant","abusive","accept","acceptable","accessible","accidental","account","accurate","achiever","acid","acidic","acoustic","acoustics","acrid","act",```

Comment: Welcome to SO! According to the error, it cannot concatenate dictionary but strings, so you need to make sure you get the key from your words and only do concatenation

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a `dict` to `random.choice`. You need to pass the list of `"data"` instead:

```py
print('random word is ' + random.choice(words[0]["data"]))
```

---

A breakdown of what's happening

```py
# Tiny example of words
words = [{"data": ["aback"]}]
```

```py
>>> words[0]
{"data": ["aback"]}
>>> words[0]["data"]
["aback"]
>>> words[0]["data"][0]
"aback"
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. but why? Doesn't words[0] only look at "aback"?

Comment: `words[0]` gets the dictionary in your list (which is the first element), then `words[0]["data"]` is the `"data"` key of that dictionary (which contains another list; your list of words).  You might find [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries_access.asp) useful

Comment: Yea it is. Thanks!!